# Assembly - JG/JNLE/JL/JNGE after CMP

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

I don't understand the `JG/JNLE/JL/JNGE` instructions, which come after CMP.

for example, If I have:

```
CMP al,dl
jg label1
```

When `al=101; dl =200`.

On what we ask the `jg`? Is it on `al>dl`? or `al-dl>0`?

Same prolbem on the next code:

```
test al,dl
jg label1
```

I don't understand what we compare, and on what we ask the "`jg`".

In other words, I don't understand when we would jump to label1, and when we wouldn't.

---

**For AT&T syntax**, note that the subtraction does the other direction, so read right to left instead of left to right:

- [Regarding cmp / jg, jle, etc in AT&T syntax assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574147/regarding-cmp-jg-jle-etc-in-att-syntax-assembly)
- [What does JL mean in at&t syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982366/what-does-jl-mean-in-att-syntax)

Comment: `test` with 2 different registers then `jg` is very weird.  But since `test`/`and` always clears OF, it's like `jns` but also jumps on ZF=0.  I assume this only exists in a made up example to get you to break down the flag-setting and flag-reading without any of the normal semantic meaning to help you figure out what it does.  Anyway, `test dl,dl` / `jg` would be totally normal as a peephole optimization to save code size but otherwise be exactly like `cmp dl,0` / `jg`.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

When you do a `cmp a,b`, the flags are set as if you had calculated `a - b`. Then the conditional jump instructions check those flags to see if the jump should be made.

In other words, the first block of code you have (with my comments added):

```
cmp  al, dl     ; set flags based on the comparison.
jg   label1     ; then jump based on the flags.
```

would jump to `label1` if and only if `al` was greater than `dl`.

You're probably better off thinking of it as `al > dl` but the two choices you have there are mathematically equivalent:

```
al          >   dl
(al - dl)   >   (dl - dl) [subtract dl from both sides]
(al - dl)   >   0         [cancel the terms on the right hand side]
```

You need to be careful when using `jg` inasmuch as it assumes your values were signed. So, if you compare the bytes `101` (`101` in two's complement) with `200` (`-56` in two's complement), the former will actually be greater. If that's not what was desired, you should use the equivalent unsigned comparison.

See [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) for more detail on jump selection, reproduced below for completeness, in the order of:

- ones that aren't signed or unsigned compares when used after CMP.
- unsigned ones.
- signed ones.

| Instruction | Description | Signed-ness | Conditions checked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JO | Jump if overflow |  | OF = 1 |
| JNO | Jump if not overflow |  | OF = 0 |
| JS | Jump if sign |  | SF = 1 |
| JNS | Jump if not sign |  | SF = 0 |
| JE JZ | Jump if equal Jump if zero |  | ZF = 1 |
| JNE JNZ | Jump if not equal Jump if not zero |  | ZF = 0 |
| JP JPE | Jump if parity Jump if parity even |  | PF = 1 |
| JNP JPO | Jump if no parity Jump if parity odd |  | PF = 0 |
| JCXZ JECXZ JRCXZ | Jump if CX is zero Jump if ECX is zero Jump if RCX is zero |  | CX = 0 ECX = 0 RCX = 0 |
|  |  |  |  |
| JB JNAE JC | Jump if below Jump if not above or equal Jump if carry | unsigned | CF = 1 |
| JNB JAE JNC | Jump if not below Jump if above or equal Jump if not carry | unsigned | CF = 0 |
| JBE JNA | Jump if below or equal Jump if not above | unsigned | CF = 1 or ZF = 1 |
| JA JNBE | Jump if above Jump if not below or equal | unsigned | CF = 0 and ZF = 0 |
|  |  |  |  |
| JL JNGE | Jump if less Jump if not greater or equal | signed | SF <> OF |
| JGE JNL | Jump if greater or equal Jump if not less | signed | SF = OF |
| JLE JNG | Jump if less or equal Jump if not greater | signed | ZF = 1 or SF <> OF |
| JG JNLE | Jump if greater Jump if not less or equal | signed | ZF = 0 and SF = OF |
|  |  |  |  |

Comment: Sorry, buy I check it now: If I have AL = 200, DL = 101. So, AL>DL, and for that, we need to jump (as you say..). But in this case, SF=0, OF=1, meaning -> SF!=OF, and jg would not take place. What I miss?

Comment: @Adam, because `jg` works on _signed_ values (200 in eight bit two's complement is actually -56). If you want to handle them as unsigned values, use `ja`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that in gdb's syntax (GAS) the order of operands for cmp (cmpl) is inversed, as you can see on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow , which lists both Intel and GAS variants.

Comment: @Nickolay: That's called AT&T syntax.  You can tell GNU tools to use GAS's flavour of Intel syntax, e.g. in your `~/.gdbinit`, put `set disassembly-flavor intel`, or `gcc -S -masm=intel`.

Comment: The conditions you list first, jo/jno and js/jns, are explicitly signed conditions.  Signed overflow, and signed-negative result.  They're not signed `cmp` *comparisons*, but they're very much signed conditions.  (Well, you can use `js` to test for the MSB of a bitfield.)  Maybe what you want is a different way to describe that grouping, instead of saying that signedness isn't relevant/appropriate.  Perhaps "ones that aren't signed or unsigned compares when used after CMP".  Otherwise those could go after the jg/jl group at the end, as sort of part of it.

Answer (score 5):

Wikibooks has a fairly good summary of [jump instructions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow). Basically, there's actually two stages:

```
cmp_instruction op1, op2
```

Which sets various flags based on the result, and

```
jmp_conditional_instruction address
```

which will execute the jump based on the results of those flags.

Compare (`cmp`) will basically compute the subtraction `op1-op2`, however, this is not stored; instead only flag results are set. So if you did `cmp eax, ebx` that's the same as saying `eax-ebx` - then deciding based on whether that is positive, negative or zero which flags to set.

More detailed reference [here](http://siyobik.info/main/reference/instruction/CMP).

Answer (score 2):

**Addition and subtraction in two's complement is the same for signed and unsigned numbers**

The key observation is that CMP is basically subtraction, and:

> In [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (integer representation used by x86), signed and unsigned addition are exactly the same operation

This allows for example hardware developers to implement it more efficiently with just one circuit.

So when you give input bytes to the x86 ADD instruction for example, it does not care if they are signed or not.

However, ADD does set a few flags depending on what happened during the operation:

- carry: unsigned addition or subtraction result does not fit in bit size, e.g.: 0xFF + 0x01 or 0x00 - 0x01

  For addition, we would need to carry 1 to the next level.
- sign: result has top bit set. I.e.: is negative if interpreted as signed.
- overflow: input top bits are both 0 and 0 or 1 and 1 and output inverted is the opposite.

  I.e. signed operation changed sigedness in an impossible way (e.g. positive + positive or negative

We can then interpret those flags in a way that makes comparison match our expectations for signed or unsigned numbers.

This interpretation is exactly what JA vs JG and JB vs JL do for us!

**Code example**

Here is GNU GAS a code snippet to make this more concrete:

```
/* 0x0 ==
 *
 * * 0 in 2's complement signed
 * * 0 in 2's complement unsigned
 */
mov $0, %al

/* 0xFF ==
 *
 * *  -1 in 2's complement signed
 * * 255 in 2's complement unsigned
 */
mov $0xFF, %bl

/* Do the operation "Is al < bl?" */
cmp %bl, %al
```

Note that AT&T syntax is "backwards": `mov src, dst`.  So you have to mentally reverse the operands for the condition codes to make sense with `cmp`.  In Intel syntax, this would be `cmp al, bl`

After this point, the following jumps would be taken:

- JB, because 0 < 255
- JNA, because !(0 > 255)
- JNL, because !(0 < -1)
- JG, because 0 > -1

Note how in this particular example the signedness mattered, e.g. JB is taken but not JL.

[Runnable example with assertions](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/58418b2a8d91fefb272f566bd74d4c4033a8d301/userland/arch/x86_64/jcc.S).

**Equals / Negated versions like JLE / JNG are just aliases**

By looking at the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals Volume 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20190606075330/https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf) section "Jcc - Jump if Condition Is Met" we see that the encodings are identical, for example:

```
Opcode  Instruction  Description
7E cb   JLE rel8     Jump short if less or equal (ZF=1 or SF ≠ OF).
7E cb   JNG rel8     Jump short if not greater (ZF=1 or SF ≠ OF).
```

Answer (score 1):

The command JG simply means: **Jump if Greater**. The result of the preceding instructions is stored in certain processor flags (in this it would test if ZF=0 and SF=OF) and jump instruction act according to their state.