# How do I translate an optimized x86-64 asm loop back to a C for loop?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I have the following:

```
foo:
   movl $0, %eax                      //result = 0
   cmpq %rsi, %rdi                    // rdi = x, rsi = y?
   jle .L2

.L3:
   addq %rdi, %rax                    //result = result + i?
   subq $1, %rdi                      //decrement?
   cmp %rdi, rsi
   jl .L3

.L2
   rep
   ret
```

And I'm trying to translate it to:

```
long foo(long x, long y)
{
    long i, result = 0;
    for (i=     ;               ;         ){

      //??

   }

 return result;
}
```

I don't know what cmpq %rsi, %rdi mean. 
Why isn't there another &eax for long i?

I would love some help in figuring this out. I don't know what I'm missing - I been going through my notes, textbook, and rest of the internet and I am stuck. It's a review question, and I've been at it for hours.

Comment: Your first task is figuring out the calling convention - what is `x`, what is `y`.

Comment: isn't the 2nd cmp supposed to be `cmpq %rdi, %rsi` too

Comment: Answer: `for (i = 0xDEADBEEF; x > y; x --) { result += x; }`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala May I ask why i = 0xDEADBEEF?

Comment: to show that the question is stupid. There is colon missing from after the label and basically `rsi` would be a variable name...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a function taking 2 parameters. Assuming this is using the gcc amd64 calling convention, it will pass the two parameters in rdi and rsi. In your C function you call these x and y.

```
long foo(long x /*rdi*/, long y /*rsi*/)
{
    //movl $0, %eax
    long result = 0;  /* rax */

    //cmpq %rsi, %rdi
    //jle .L2
    if (x > y) {
        do {
            //addq %rdi, %rax
            result += x;

            //subq $1, %rdi
            --x;

            //cmp %rdi, rsi
            //jl .L3            
        } while (x > y);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to incorporate `long i` and keep everything in the 'for' loop?

Comment: @Ian: The point is that your assembly code doesn't translate to a for loop using `long i`. It translates to a do-while loop.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: But that *is* how a C `for()` loop compiles to asm, as an idiomatic loop with a conditional branch at the *bottom*.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926).  If the compiler can't prove that the loop condition is true the first time, you get a cmp/jcc to skip over the loop entirely if it needs to run zero times.  This could well be `gcc -O1` output (except for the missing `%` on `rsi`, and the missing `:` on `.L2`)  Gcc doesn't look for the xor-zeroing peephole optimization at `-O1`, but will do normal loop stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know what `cmpq %rsi, %rdi` mean

That's AT&T syntax for `cmp rdi, rsi`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html

You can look up the details of what a single instruction does in an ISA manual.

More importantly, `cmp`/`jcc` like `cmp %rsi,%rdi`/`jl` is like `jump if rdi<rsi`. 
 [Assembly - JG/JNLE/JL/JNGE after CMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617877/assembly-jg-jnle-jl-jnge-after-cmp).  If you go through all the details of how `cmp` sets flags, and which flags each [`jcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html) condition checks, you can verify that it's correct, but it's *much* easier to just use the semantic meaning of JL = Jump on Less-than (assuming flags were set by a `cmp`) to remember what they do.

(It's reversed because of AT&T syntax; `jcc` predicates have the right semantic meaning for Intel syntax.  This is one of the major reasons I usually prefer Intel syntax, but you can get used to AT&T syntax.)

---

**From the use of `rdi` and `rsi` as inputs** (reading them without / before writing them), they're the arg-passing registers.  So this is the x86-64 System V calling convention, where integer args are passed in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9, then on the stack.  ([What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6) covers function calls as well as system calls).  The other major x86-64 calling convention is Windows x64, which passes the first 2 args in RCX and RDX (if they're both integer types).

So yes, x=RDI and y=RSI.  And yes, result=RAX.  (writing to EAX zero-extends into RAX).

---

From the code structure (not storing/reloading every C variable to memory between statements), it's compiled with some level of optimization enabled, so **the `for()` loop turned into a normal asm loop with the conditional branch at the bottom.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)**  (@BrianWalker's answer shows the asm loop transliterated back to C, with no attempt to form it back into an idiomatic `for` loop.)

From the cmp/jcc ahead of the loop, we can tell that the compiler can't prove the loop runs a non-zero number of iterations.  So whatever the `for()` loop condition is, it might be false the first time.  (That's unsurprising given signed integers.)

Since **we don't see a separate register being used for `i`**, we can conclude that **optimization reused another var's register for `i`**.  Like probably `for(i=x;`, and then with the original value of `x`  being unused for the rest of the function, it's "dead" and the compiler can just use RDI as `i`, destroying the original value of `x`.

I guessed `i=x` instead of `y` because RDI is the arg register that's modified inside the loop.  We expect that the C source modifies `i` and `result` inside the loop, and presumably doesn't modify it's input variables `x` and `y`.  It would make no sense to do `i=y` and then do stuff like `x--`, although that would be another valid way of decompiling.

**`cmp %rdi, %rsi` / `jl .L3` means the loop condition to (re)enter the loop is `rsi-rdi < 0` (signed), or `i<y`.**

The cmp/jcc *before* the loop is checking the opposite condition; notice that the operands are reversed and it's checking `jle`, i.e. `jng`.  So that makes sense, it really is same loop condition peeled out of the loop and implemented differently.  Thus it's compatible with the C source being a plain `for()` loop with one condition.

**`sub $1, %rdi` is obviously `i--` or `--i`**.  We can do that inside the `for()`, or at the bottom of the loop body.  The simplest and most idiomatic place to put it is in the 3rd section of the `for(;;)` statement.

`addq %rdi, %rax` is obviously adding `i` to `result`.  We already know what RDI and RAX are in this function.

**Putting the pieces together, we arrive at:**

```
long foo(long x, long y)
{
    long i, result = 0;
    for (i= x    ;    i>y    ;    i-- ){
        result += i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

### Which compiler made this code?

**From the `.L3:` label names, this looks like output from `gcc`**.  (Which somehow got corrupted, removing the `:` from `.L2`, and more importantly removing the `%` from `%rsi` in one cmp.  Make sure you copy/paste code into SO questions to avoid this.)

So it may be possible with the right gcc version/options to get exactly this asm back out for some C input.  It's probably `gcc -O1`, because `movl $0, %eax` rules out `-O2` and higher (where GCC would look for the `xor %eax,%eax` peephole optimization for zeroing a register efficiently).  But it's not `-O0` because that would be storing/reloading the loop counter to memory.  And `-Og` (optimize a bit, for debugging) likes to use a `jmp` to the loop condition instead of a separate `cmp/jcc` to skip the loop.  This level of detail is basically irrelevant for simply decompiling to C that does the same thing.

The `rep ret` is another sign of gcc; gcc7 and earlier used this in their default `tune=generic` output for `ret` that's reached as a branch target or a fall-through from a `jcc`,  because of AMD K8/K10 branch prediction.  [What does `rep ret` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526361/what-does-rep-ret-mean)

gcc8 and later will still use it with `-mtune=k8` or `-mtune=barcelona`.  But we can rule that out because that tuning option would use `dec %rdi` instead of `subq $1, %rdi`.  (Only a few modern CPUs have any problems with `inc/dec` leaving CF unmodified, for register operands.  [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter))

gcc4.8 and later put `rep ret` on the same line.  gcc4.7 and earlier print it as you've shown, with the `rep` prefix on the line before.

gcc4.7 and later like to put the initial branch *before* the `mov $0, %eax`, which looks like a missed optimization.  It means they need a separate `return 0` path out of the function, which contains another `mov $0, %eax`.

**gcc4.6.4 `-O1` reproduces your output *exactly*, for the source shown above, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'long+foo(long+x,+long+y)%0A%7B%0A++++long+i,+result+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(i%3D+x++++%3B++++i%3Ey++++%3B++++i--+)%7B%0A++++++++result+%2B%3D+i%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++return+result%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+also+the+same+asm+output,+using+i%3Dy+and+then+using+it+differently.%0Along+foo2(long+x,+long+y)%0A%7B%0A++++long+i,+result+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(i%3D+y++++%3B++++x%3Ei++++%3B++++x--+)%7B%0A++++++result+%2B%3D+x%3B%0A+++%7D%0A%0A+return+result%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g464,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O1+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.6.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**

```
# compiled with gcc4.6.4 -O1 -fverbose-asm
foo:
        movl    $0, %eax        #, result
        cmpq    %rsi, %rdi      # y, x
        jle     .L2       #,
.L3:
        addq    %rdi, %rax      # i, result
        subq    $1, %rdi        #, i
        cmpq    %rdi, %rsi      # i, y
        jl      .L3 #,
.L2:
        rep
        ret
```

So does this other version which uses `i=y`.  Of course there are many things we could add that would optimize away, like maybe `i=y+1` and then having a loop condition like `x>--i`.  (Signed overflow is undefined behaviour in C, so the compiler can assume it doesn't happen.)

```
// also the same asm output, using i=y but modifying x in the loop.
long foo2(long x, long y) {
  long i, result = 0;
  for (i= y    ;    x>i    ;    x-- ){
      result += x;
   }
   return result;
}
```

---

#### In practice the way I actually reversed this:

- I copy/pasted the C template into Godbolt (https://godbolt.org/). I could see right away (from the `mov $0` instead of xor-zero, and from the label names) that it looked like `gcc -O1` output, so I put in that command line option and picked an old-ish version of gcc like gcc6.  (Turns out this asm was actually from a much older gcc).
- I tried an initial guess like `x<y` based on the cmp/jcc, and `i++` (before I'd actually read the rest of the asm carefully *at all*), because for loops often use `i++`.  The trivial-looking infinite-loop asm output showed me that was obviously wrong :P
- I guessed that i=x, but after taking a wrong turn with a version that did `result += x` but `i--`, I realized that `i` was a distraction and at first simplified by not using `i` at all.  I just used `x--` while first reversing it because obviously RDI=x.  (I know the x86-64 System V calling convention well enough to see that instantly.)
- After looking at the loop body, the `result += x` and `x--` were totally obvious from the `add` and `sub` instructions.
- `cmp/jl` was obviously a `something < something` loop condition involving the 2 input vars.
- I wasn't sure I if it was `x<y` or `y<x`, and newer gcc versions were using `jne` as the loop condition.  I think at that point I cheated and looked at Brian's answer to check it really was `x > y`, instead of taking a minute to work through the actual logic.  **But once I had figured out it was `x--`, only `x>y` made sense.**  The other one would be true until wraparound if it entered the loop at all, but signed overflow is undefined behaviour in C.
- Then I looked at some older gcc versions to see if any made asm more like in the question.
- Then I went back and replaced `x` with `i` inside the loop.

If this seems kind of haphazard and slapdash, that's because this loop is so tiny that I didn't expect to have any trouble figuring it out, and I was more interested in finding source + gcc version that exactly reproduced it, rather than the original problem of just reversing it at all.

(I'm not saying beginners should find it that easy, I'm just documenting *my* thought process in case anyone's curious.)