# How does the assembly TEST instruction work with these jump instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, conditional-statements

Using AT&T assembly syntax, I'm trying to understand how `testl` is used in assembly code. Specifically:

```
testl  %edx, %edx
jle    .L3
```

I know `testl` does a bitwise `and` of the same value to set the condition flags, but how can I interpret 'jump if less than or equal to' if it isn't comparing two values?

Comment: Not sure it's actually a dup, but you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557279/assembly-jle-jmp-instruction-example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the official documentation from Intel on test:

```
Operation
TEMP ← SRC1 AND SRC2;
SF ← MSB(TEMP);
IF TEMP = 0
    THEN ZF ← 1;
    ELSE ZF ← 0;
FI:
PF ← BitwiseXNOR(TEMP[0:7]);
CF ← 0;
OF ← 0;
```

And the same on jle:

```
Jump if less or equal (ZF=1 or SF≠OF)
```

So, the jump will be performed if `edx` is 0 (because `edx AND edx = edx` and that's 0 only when `edx` is 0, and because `ZF` is set to 1 when the result of `AND` is 0) or if the most significant bit of `edx` is 1 (because `SF = most significant bit` of `edx AND edx` (or, equivalently, of `edx` itself) and `OF` is always 0, which means `SF ≠ OF` is only true when `SF ≠ 0`).

IOW, the jump will be performed only if `edx` is ≤ 0 when interpreted as a signed integer or, equivalently, when `edx` is either 0 or greater or equal than 0x80000000 when interpreted as an unsigned integer.

Comment: +1, great catch about the signed integers. That makes a lot more sense than checking for `0 or >= 0x80000000`!

Comment: IOW, in the case of signed integers, the jump instructions always compares the tested value (testl) to 0. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing else to effectively compare with. If you did `cmp edx, 5` or `sub edx, 5`, you'd be looking at `edx-5` vs 0 instead of just `edx` vs 0.

Answer (score 4):

`TESTL` with identical arguments (like `edx` and `edx`) sets the flags based on the value of that argument itself (since x AND x is identical to x). So we can forget about the `AND` altogether here since it's discarded - all we need to concern ourselves with is the value in `edx`.

With `TESTL`, the zero flag `ZF` is set to 1 only if the value is zero. `TESTL` also forces the overflow flag `OF` to 0 and sets the sign flag `SF` only if the high bit is set.

`JLE` will then jump if either `ZF` is set to 1, or `SF <> OF`.

So, the jump will execute if either:

- `edx` was zero; or
- `edx` had its high bit set.

Hence it will jump for `edx` values of `0` or `0x80000000 - 0xffffffff`.

Most likely this is a check to ensure that the number is a natural number `0x00000001 - 0x7fffffff`, the jump would be to an error handling routine of some sort and a valid natural number would continue without the jump, something like:

```
loop_for_number:
    call   get_number_into_edx
    testl  %edx, %edx
    jle    loop_for_number

    ; carry on here knowing that edx >= 1
```

---

For a description of the various jumps and the flags they use, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617877/assembly-jg-jnle-jl-jnge-after-cmp/9617990#9617990).

Answer (score 3):

In x86 assembly almost all conditional jumps are based on flags (except `jcxz`, `jecxz`, `loop` and `loopne`/ `loopnz`). This means that all that matters are the values the flags have.

`jle` is synonymous with `jng`. The jump condition is `ZF = 1 or SF <> OF`. You may want to check [Intel x86 JUMP quick reference](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html).

`test` does set all flags except `AF` [link](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/test.html), so everything looks good so far.

According to [this link](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~cpatel2/links/310/slides/lab_slides/lab_lect03_arith_control.pdf) logical operations always zero `OF`. That means your jump would practically be `ZF = 1 or SF = 1`, so in your code `jle` would jump if `edx` was `0` or between range `0x80000000` ... `0xffffffff`.